# Why can't I ssh to the Ubuntu VM in azure?

Tags: ssh, azure, ubuntu-14.04

I created a fresh VM with Ubuntu 14.04 image in windows azure. I'm trying to connect the VM with with ssh. But it showing something like. Can you help me to understand on what went wrong here?

Here is the output from the terminal.

```
ssh -v ****.cloudapp.net : 22                     
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ***.cloudapp.net [104.42.12.189] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA a2:be:a9:21:ca:a2:e3:96:e1:b3:c3:e9:63:6d:c5:ac
debug1: Host '***.cloudapp.net' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:28
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@*****.cloudapp.net's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to *****.cloudapp.net ([104.42.12.189]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_IN
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = en_IN
debug1: Sending command: : 22
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2908, received 2228 bytes, in 0.8 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 3585.2, received 2746.8
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command (`ssh -v example.cloudapp.net : 22`) says to connect to `example.cloudapp.net` and then execute the command `: 22` and exit.

From what I can see it succeeds in doing this.

I would guess that you tried to specify the port number(?) but that is not how you do it. First of all, port 22 is default for ssh, so there's no need to specify it but if you need to specify a port, use `-p`.

For some info on what `: 22` means:

```
$ type :
: is a shell builtin
$ help :
:: :
    Null command.

    No effect; the command does nothing.

    Exit Status:
    Always succeeds.
$
```

Comment: I thought I should specify the port number. thanks for the answer.

Comment: If you deploy multiple vm's to the same cloudapp.net container, then each vm will have a unique ssh port. In that case, you *will* need to specify the port, when it's not 22.